# Draw line from path segment data

Tags: javascript, xml, svg

I have the following XML which I'm trying to work out, shot in the dark.

Can anyone help me construct a path (SVG, Canvas) using the XML data below.

Looking for anything that will help me produce a path based on this information.

```
<path>
  <segment>
    <dx>0</dx>
    <dy>15</dy>
    <to>
      <x>359</x>
      <y>701</y>
    </to>
    <from>
      <x>359</x>
      <y>686</y>
    </from>
  </segment>
</path>
```

I know that the above XML forms part of a path which is part of a series of connecting lines. So multiple nodes with XML similar to the above connecting nodes in a HTML view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be something like the following:

```
<line x1="359" y1="686" x2="359" y2="701" stroke="black" stroke-width="1"/>
```

or if you need a path:

```
<path d="M 359,686 L 359,701" stroke="black" stroke-width="1"/>
```

or if there are multiple line segments, you may choose to use a polyline:

```
<polyline points="359,686, 359,701, etc,etc..." stroke="black" stroke-width="1"/>
```

You will need to set stroke colour and width because, by default, they are not drawn. Either set them in the path/line element, or in a parent container object such as the `<svg>` itself, or a `<g`> (group).

It is not clear to me what `dx` and `dy` are supposed to do, so I am ignoring those.  Where did this XML come from?